# recursive function int sum (int * x, int n)?

Tags: c, recursion

Recursive C function  int sum (int * x, int n) which returns the number of elements
of array which in binary inscription has more than two 1.( for example : binary elements with more than two 1 are: 111001, 11011...)

I have problem with this function. I've tried :

```
int sum(int *x,int n)
{
if(n==1)return *x;
else
return ( x[n-1]+sum(x+1,n-1));
}
```

but this function does not work.... Can anyone help me?

Comment: why does this have to be recursive?

Comment: The problem is not clear.

Comment: Of course it doesn't work, you don't check the array elements binary representation.

Comment: @Jite, it works by virtue of pointer arithmetic

Comment: @StoryTeller Ofc, brain-f*kup, thinking you can't add `1` to `value` of `x` and expect it to point to next member of the array, hah. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The recursive step is wrong. It should be:

```
return x[0] + sum(x + 1, n - 1);
```

It's adding the last element, while recursively stepping along the array. That ends up all wrong, it should add the first, i.e. the "head" of the array (if seen as a list).

Answer (score 0):

As per your description you are using wrong logic

> Recursive C function int sum (int * x, int n) which returns the number
>   of elements of array which in binary inscription has more than two 1

```
int NumberOfSetBits(int i)
{
    i = i - ((i >> 1) & 0x55555555);
    i = (i & 0x33333333) + ((i >> 2) & 0x33333333);
    return (((i + (i >> 4)) & 0x0F0F0F0F) * 0x01010101) >> 24;
}

int sum(int *x,int n)
{
    static int count = 0;
    if(NumberOfSetBits(*x) > 2)
      count++;    

    if(n==1)
        return count;
    else
        return sum(x+1,n-1);
}
```

Comment: No, it looks like his function (tries to) sum all the elements of array `x[]`.